# A user types a word and a number on a single line. Read them into the provided variables. Then print

Tags: c, string, input, scanf

It takes in a word and a number, I can't seem to understand why the number variable won't receive the input, help please.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

   char userWord[20];

   int userNum;

   scanf("%s", userWord);

   printf("%s_", userWord);

   scanf("%s", userNum);

   printf("%d\n", userNum);


   return 0;
}
```

Should be:

Input: Stop 7

Output: Stop_7

What I get:

Input: Stop 7

Output: Stop_0

Comment: Please revisit the documentation for `scanf` about format specifiers and what should be provided as arguments..

Comment: `scanf("%s", userNum);` --> `scanf("%d", &userNum);`

Comment: Also note New C Programmers who fail to check the **return** of `scanf` are lined up and systematically *shot at sunrise...* You have three conditions to **validate** (1) `EOF` returned, (2) less than the number of conversions -- indicating a *matching* or *input* failure, or (3) equal to the number of conversion indicating all valid conversions took place. Start now, protect against all three every time, account for any characters that remain in the input buffer -- and you can correctly use `scanf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
scanf("%s", userNum);
```

to

```
scanf("%d", &userNum);
```

Answer (score 1):

You used format `%s` for reading in an integral value; it should have been `%d`.
Once having fixed this (i.e. by writing `scanf("%d", &userNum);`, note that your code will read in a string and a number even if the string and the number were not in the same line (cf., for example, [cppreferene/scanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) concerning format `%s` and treatment of white spaces). Further, you will run into undefined behaviour if a user enters a string with more than 19 characters (without any white space in between), because you then exceed your `userWord`-array.

To overcome both, you could read in a line with `fgets`, then use `sscanf` to parse the line. Note that you can parse the line in one command; the result of `scanf` is then the number of successfully read items. Further, note the `%19s`, which limits the input to 19 characters (+ the final string termination character `'\0'`):

```
int main() {
    char line[100];
    if (fgets(line,100,stdin)) {
        char userWord[20];
        int userNum;

        if (sscanf(line, "%19s %d", userWord, &userNum) != 2) {
            printf("invalid input.\n");
        } else {
            printf("word:'%s'; number: %d", userWord, userNum);
        }
    }
}
```